# How do I make a spinning wheel circular gradient in CSS

Tags: css, gradient

I want to make a circle with a rainbow gradient that goes 360deg relative to the center. It should look something like this:

[image: circle with a rainbow gradient]

Is it possible to do with CSS or should I upload image as a background?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge this is not possible in CSS, though you may be able to do something complicated with transforms to get that effect. Your best bet would be to use a background image.

Comment: ...or SVG but that would be pretty complex.